# Should SSIS *.dtsx files be marked as -diff in .gitattributes

Tags: sql-server, git, ssis

I'm using git to version control SSIS packages and I know that SSIS generates some crazy XML that is going to badly confuse any merge algorithms.

I'd like to know if having the following line in my .gitattributes file is the correct thing to do:

> *.dtsx -diff

I believe this will stop git from attempting to merge the file, which is what I would like.

Am I correct in thinking that this also stops git from generating deltas and therefore stores every change as a whole file? (and therefore, takes up more storage)

My repository also holds the source for the database schema and any other source files, so I'm thinking that switching the repo to fast forward only is not appropriate.

Comment: No idea about git itself but treating SSIS packages as binaries for version control isn't unheard of. With experience, you can get an approximate idea of what has changed between versions an SSIS package. [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/) is handy in this because it has a "smart diff" function to help eliminate the layout noise. That only helps you in code reviews though - Oh,  I see you went from Full Cache to Partial Cache on this lookup. In terms of attempting to merge two sets of possibly conflicting changes, ain't nobody got time for that

Comment: For SQL Server versions 2012+, the DTSX XML format has changed to make it easier to grok diffs making BIDS Helper less relevant
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2011/08/10/package-format-changes-in-sql-server-denali/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want files to be merged in git, you need to use the -merge attribute. That way you can still be able to 'diff'.

We also treat packages as binaries, that does imply you will need to do changes multiple times if you need to do a patch from a branch and also need it in your main tree.